# What does H.V. mean in music notation?

Tags: notation, trumpet

On a music sheet I am reading, the letters "H.V." (without quotation marks) are written occasionally just above specific notes, above the top line of a bar, but lower than where chords are written, and in a smaller font. The music sheet is for trumpet. I have tried googling, as well as looking for it on here, but without finding anything.

Guessing from the acronym and the context, I thought it might mean high volume, but I can't find anything by googling that either.

Thanks for any help

Comment: "Half valve", perhaps?

Comment: What is the piece and what instrument is it for?  Can you post an image, so we can see it in context?

Comment: It's a jazz piece originally written for Bb trumpet, and I am transposing it for guitar. HV seems to mean half-valve, and I now wonder if it is similar to a bend on guitar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is jazz/swing music, then quite possibly "Half - valve,"  as described in the online [Dolmetsch](http://www.dolmetsch.com/defsh.htm) dictionary,

> the opening of stops or valves on instruments like the trumpet,
>   French horn, cornet and tuba, used by jazz musicians when they are
>   approaching a glissando, attempting to change the pitch of a tone
>   without hitting the note or its closest interval, and in the process
>   of highlighting blue notes, for vibrato effects and tremolos

Comment: Sounds right, this is jazz music. If I understand correctly, a glissando by half-valve on the trumpet would be similar to a bend on the guitar? (That is my target instrument for this trumpet piece)